# How to upgrade apache httpd to latest version (2.4.34) on Centos 7.5.1804?

Tags: centos7, httpd, http2

Is there a "simple" way to upgrade Centos 7.5.1804's version of httpd in order to support http/2?  Currently running Apache/2.4.6 and PHP 7.0.30.

For this production server, compiling from source is not an option.  Was hoping there's an EPEL or other repo that has the latest version and is a drop-in upgrade.

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/774919/http-2-on-centos-7-on-apache-with-php7), but it's from 2016.  Hoping there's a better answer now.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Centos is well known for it's stability and long term support. If the version that you are looking for is not available from the package manager, you will have to build from the source.

Comment: Check the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720703/how-to-enable-http2-on-centos7