# How to enable http/2 from a Centos Package/yum?

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, centos7

I'm running the following version of Apache on Centos 7:

httpd.x86_64                          2.4.6-97.el7.centos.5          @updates

httpd-tools.x86_64                    2.4.6-97.el7.centos.5          @updates

This is the default package that came with the system.  I want to be able to support http/2 but the instructions I have found require me to build/configure the software with that parameter.  However, I'm using a standard package for ease of update.  Is there a way to enable this feature and still use the same update tree?  Or is there a better package/repo to use?   Or is there a way I can configure the existing installation to enable http 2.0?   I looked and I didn't see mod_http2.so - is there a way to install that and then enable it via configuration so I don't have to re-build Apache from scratch?

NOTE: There is an existing question ( [HTTP/2 on CentOS 7 on Apache with PHP7](https://serverfault.com/questions/774919/http-2-on-centos-7-on-apache-with-php7) ) about this but it's 5 years old and I'm hoping for a more updated answer since at the time it was said http/2 was not as stable/supported

Comment: if not enabled by default on debian you need to add an additional module to apache, yum should be able to find it but im unfamiliar with it

Comment: Since base versions of the distributions don't receive feature updates for their packages, only security fixes, the linked question most probably is still current.

Comment: The first answer on this question is a much better answer to both questions.

Answer (score 3):

CentOS7 by default is stuck with Apache httpd 2.4.6 which doesn't provide the `mod_http2.so` module to implement HTTP/2.

Here's how to do with supported software and without recompilation:

- enable the [Software Collections Repository](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL)

  These are supported additional packages including newer versions of existing packages. They install in a separate directory (usually `/opt/rh`) so they won't clash with the original version. This also means there's a bit more effort to use some of their features.

  ```
  yum install centos-release-scl
  ```

  This will install a new repository with the additional packages
- Install `httpd24`

  ```
  yum install httpd24
  ```

  which mostly will pull the actual package `httpd24-httpd` and more importantly for this answer, will pull in turn `httpd24-libnghttp2`: A library implementing the HTTP/2 protocol.
- configure the newer installation in its own configuration directories

  Like many [SCL](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) packages, this package is intended to be installed without clashing with the package it's replacing, rather than updating it. Most of the configuration files usually found in `/etc/httpd` are now found in `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd`.

  So please copy and adapt (if there are some absolute directory references in configurations etc.) the settings over the new place: `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd`

  This version comes with HTTP/2 enabled:

  ```
  # grep -r http2 /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/
  /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf:LoadModule http2_module modules/mod_http2.so
  ```
- verify syntax etc.

  This is part of SCL peculiarities. One must run preparatory commands to use the correct path and libraries for the added components.

  Interactively (but a non-interactive command could be run immediately instead):

  ```
  # scl enable httpd24 -- bash -l
  ```

  The new shell inherits additional environment:

  ```
  # printenv |grep /opt/rh
  MANPATH=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/share/man:
  LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64
  PATH=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/bin
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
  ```

  and can now run commands like:

  ```
  # httpd -v
  Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Red Hat)
  Server built:   Feb  1 2022 14:11:48
  ```
- Switch the service over

  *systemd* services are already made to use this new environment, so nothing related to the previous bullet is needed here

  ```
  systemctl disable --now httpd
  systemctl enable --now httpd24-httpd
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent response!

Comment: If it solved your question, feel free to mark the answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: So for Amazon Linux, (this link: https://gist.github.com/dasgoll/42cc52cbac6fc6f5bdec) uses `yum-config-manager --enable epe` then `yum -y install scl-utils`. But httpd24 is no where to be found when running `yum install httpd24`. Stumbled across this: https://wiki.wocommunity.org/display/documentation/Installing+a+deployment+environment+on+RedHat%2C+CentOS+or+Amazon+Linux

Comment: This didn't work for me, the directory /opt/rh is there but empty, as is /etc/scl/conf. Same setup. If I figure out why I'll post back.

Answer (score -2):

See Red Hat / Fedora instructions here: https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-enable-http-2-in-apache-on-linux-system/

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. They become useless when the link dies. Instead, post the essence of the link and add the link for reference.

Comment: What point is this? The OP specifically says CentOS 7! Not being rude.