# Apache - http/2 enabled but still feeding http/1.1 on requests

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, http2

Apache/2.4.34 (Red Hat) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips on CentOS 7, PHP 7.4.33, I have installed and enabled http/2 following the guide at [How to enable http/2 from a Centos Package/yum?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1098821/how-to-enable-http-2-from-a-centos-package-yum?newreg=d8d805dc35164da4b40e97fc55fc6274). No errors are reported and the module is loaded but pages remain served over http/1.1.

I have moved from prefork mpm to event, so this is not the issue.

This is not a browser cache issue.

Apache has been restarted multiple times.

The conf files include:

`Protocols h2 http/1.1`

SSL Protocol directive is:

`SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3`

Output of httpd -V:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Red Hat)
Server built:   Oct 11 2022 12:56:44
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:79
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

apachectl -M:

```
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 cache_socache_module (shared)
 data_module (shared)
 dbd_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 dumpio_module (shared)
 echo_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 http2_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 macro_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 request_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_plain_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_dbm_module (shared)
 socache_memcache_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 watchdog_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_hcheck_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_uwsgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 systemd_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
```

https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test:

```
HTTP/2 protocol is not supported.
ALPN extension is not supported.
```

updated with virtual hosts

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName ###
    ServerAlias www ###
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/###.ro/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/###/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/###/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Regarding `Protocols h2 http/1.1`, is that in the general configuration, or under a specific virtual host?  Is it being overridden with settings against your virtual host?  (e.g. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html#basic-config)

Comment: Also - are you using HTTPS?  If not you should also include `h2c` (i.e. `Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1`) as it seems `h2` is http/2 over TLS, whilst `h2c` is http/2 over TCP (i.e. a non-secure transport layer).

Comment: Is there anything between your web server and the internet (reverse proxy / load balancer / firewall / etc)?  If so, potentially that may also need config changed to support `http/2`.

Comment: I've updated the protocols to `Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1` and they are under a specific virtual host.

Comment: What does your `virtualhost` look like - i.e. are you specifying any IP/Port/ServerName/ServerAlias values?  Are you serving content over HTTP or HTTPS?  If HTTPS, do you have a valid cert with a SAN list covering all relevant domains?  Can you access the site in the browser (i.e. irrespective of http/1.1 vs http/2).

Comment: I've updated the question with virtulhost file.
The website is accesible form browser with http/1.1

Comment: From what you've shared above, all looks fine with your config.  I don't know much about CentOS, but found this - https://serverfault.com/a/1098826/137255 - any help?

Comment: I've tried what's written on that answer. I'll check if there's something in reverse proxy / load balancer / firewall. I'll update when i've found somehing.

Comment: Everthin seemed fine, but it didn’t work so I’ve given up. I will try a newer version or CentOS or maybe try on Ubuntu. 
Thanks for the ideas!